# At $t=25$, a variable becomes half of its initial value, the formula for its value is $Q(t) = Q_0\cdot e^{-kt}$, find $k$

Tags: calculus

> The disintegration of a radioactive substance is well modeled by a law
> of the type:
>
> $$Q(t) = Q_0\cdot e^{-kt}$$
>
> being $Q(t)$ the remaining mass, at instant $t$, of an initial
> quantity $Q_0$, that corresponds to the instant $t=0$.
>
> Substance A has
> an half-life time of 25 years.
>
> Write the law for the disintegration of substance A, in function of
> $Q_0$ and for $t$, given in years.

I tried:

$$Q(25) = \frac{Q_0}{2},\\ e^{-k25} = \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow e^{k25} = 2 \Leftrightarrow e^k = \sqrt[25]{2} \Leftrightarrow k = ln(\sqrt[25]{2}) \approx .0277$$

And so

$$Q(t) = Q_0e^{ln(\sqrt[25]{2})t}$$

However, my book says the solution is
$$Q(t) = Q_0e^{\frac{ln(0.5)}{25}t}$$

So, according to my book, $k = \frac{ln(0.5)}{25} = -.0277$

It seems I changed the sign somewhere. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is the book perhaps giving you $-k$ as an answer?

Comment: Book is correct. Think about it physically, mass is decreasing. It has to have negative kinetics.

Comment: @Dando18 It doesn't give me the specific value for $k$, it just gives me the final formula and I guessed the value of $k$ from there (you can see it on my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \mathrm{e}^{-k25}=\frac{1}{2} $$
$$ \ln(\mathrm{e}^{-k25})=\ln(0.5) $$
$$ -k25=\ln(0.5) $$
$$ k=\frac{-\ln(0.5)}{25}\approx 0.277$$

So the final formula would be:
$$ Q(t)=Q_0\: \mathrm{e}^{-0.277t}$$
You're correct that the value of $k$ is positive, but the equation has a negative sign before the $k$, which is why it appears negative in the final result.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks